# how can i retrieve page informations in solr?

Tags: html, solr, hyperlink, nutch

I'm new in nutch and solr.
I use nutch to crawl web sites and I use solr to indexing theese pages.
Is there a method for retrieve the content of a link in the solr database?

for Example

- if I have indexing http://www.prova.com/prova.html
- this page contains the text "this is a new page"
- in solr, is there the text page saved somewhere?

Thanks

Danilo

Answer (score 0):

The text of the page is stored in a field named "content". Note that this is not the raw page, but a parsed version of the page. The searchable content should appear here, but not things like meta tags and javascript.

Comment: Hi Mike. But in java how can i retrieve this field content? thanks